# Why does RDF seem so convoluted

Tags: xml, rdf

So here is an entry in rdf format.  I'd like to understand why some parts of it seem so convoluted.

```
<pgterms:file rdf:about="&f;dirs/3/1/9/0/31900/31900-8.zip">
  <dc:format><dcterms:IMT><rdf:value>text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"</rdf:value></dcterms:IMT></dc:format>
  <dc:format><dcterms:IMT><rdf:value>application/zip</rdf:value></dcterms:IMT></dc:format>
  <dcterms:extent>193120</dcterms:extent>
  <dcterms:modified><dcterms:W3CDTF><rdf:value>2010-04-06</rdf:value></dcterms:W3CDTF></dcterms:modified>
  <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="#etext31900" />
</pgterms:file>
```

In particular, this value:

```
<dc:format><dcterms:IMT><rdf:value>text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"</rdf:value></dcterms:IMT></dc:format>
```

Why does it need both a `dcterms:IMT` AND an `rdf:value` portion?  This just seems like a lot of bloat for what appears to be little practical benefit.  Since it is already using MIME types, it just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that RDF is well-designed. This assumption is faulty. :)

Comment: Not sure if it is fatigue (from looking @ RDF) or what, but I found that pretty funny.

Comment: For a more serious answer: I'm not super familiar with RDF (which is why I'm making this a comment not an answer), but the differing prefixes ("rdf", "pgterms", "dc", "dcterms"...) indicate that you're mixing elements from a bunch of different namespaces, suggesting that various parts of this mess were developed independently. So there's no unifying design for the whole thing.

Comment: Probably should note that I'm trying to read the catalog from Project Gutenberg  http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Feeds#The_Project_Gutenberg_Catalog_in_RDF.2FXML_Format

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why does xml have so many angle brackets my eyes hurt....because it was meant to be read by a parser not by humans.

Your sample is not rdf (rdf is the framework), it is rdf/xml, one possible serialzation of a graph in the framework.  [Turtle/n3](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/) is much prettier serialization. [N-Triples](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/) is super simple.

Some very small examples that don't cover any real details but...

**RDF/XML:**

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/">
    <dc:creator>Art Barstow</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Dave Beckett</dc:creator>
    <dc:publisher rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**N-Triples**

```
<http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/> <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator> "Dave Beckett" .
<http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/> <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator> "Art Barstow" .
<http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/> <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/publisher> <http://www.w3.org/> .
```

**N3**

```
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>

<http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/> 
     dc:creator "Dave Beckett";
     dc:creator "Art Barstow";
     dc:publisher <http://www.w3.org/>.
```

**EDIT:** you can stop reading, this is just the example provided by OP in different serialization.  To answer to the question

> Why does it need both a dcterms:IMT AND an rdf:value portion?

rdf/xml has to do kind of a stutter-step when there are "Blank Nodes".  you can see below that N-Triples writes the blank nodes out and n3 attempts to make it more obvious what the relations are.
All of these are serialzations of the same rdf graph.

**RDF/XML** slightly modified (namespace added) so it parses:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
         xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
         xmlns:pgterms="http://www.gutenberg.org/rdfterms/">
<pgterms:file rdf:about="/home/me/dirs/3/1/9/0/31900/31900-8.zip">
  <dc:format><dcterms:IMT><rdf:value>text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"</rdf:value></dcterms:IMT></dc:format>
  <dc:format><dcterms:IMT><rdf:value>application/zip</rdf:value></dcterms:IMT></dc:format>
  <dcterms:extent>193120</dcterms:extent>
  <dcterms:modified><dcterms:W3CDTF><rdf:value>2010-04-06</rdf:value></dcterms:W3CDTF></dcterms:modified>
  <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="#etext31900" />
</pgterms:file>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**N-Triples**

```
</home/me/dirs/3/1/9/0/31900/31900-8.zip> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.gutenberg.org/rdfterms/file> .
</home/me/dirs/3/1/9/0/31900/31900-8.zip> <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/format> _:LqSOByLi19 .
</home/me/dirs/3/1/9/0/31900/31900-8.zip> <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/format> _:LqSOByLi20 .
</home/me/dirs/3/1/9/0/31900/31900-8.zip> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/isFormatOf> <#etext31900> .
</home/me/dirs/3/1/9/0/31900/31900-8.zip> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/modified> _:LqSOByLi21 .
</home/me/dirs/3/1/9/0/31900/31900-8.zip> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/extent> "193120" .
_:LqSOByLi21 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/W3CDTF> .
_:LqSOByLi21 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#value> "2010-04-06" .
_:LqSOByLi20 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT> .
_:LqSOByLi20 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#value> "application/zip" .
_:LqSOByLi19 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT> .
_:LqSOByLi19 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#value> "text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" .
```

**N3/Turtle**

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix pgterms: <http://www.gutenberg.org/rdfterms/> .

</home/me/dirs/3/1/9/0/31900/31900-8.zip> a pg:file;
    dc:format 
        [ a dcterms:IMT;  rdf:value "text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" ],
        [ a dcterms:IMT;  rdf:value "application/zip" ];
    dcterms:extent "193120";
    dcterms:isFormatOf <#etext31900>;
    dcterms:modified [ a dcterms:W3CDTF; rdf:value "2010-04-06" ] .
```

Note: N3 is even prettier [if it's colored](http://www.openvest.com/trac/wiki/n3SyntaxHighlighting)

**EDIT 2:**
The above describes that there is a bnode but as to why there is one....the `dcterms:modified` predicate in the last line of the *N3* serialization above could (I wish) be viewed more like:

```
dcterms:modified "2010-04-06"^^dcterms:W3CDTF
# vs
dcterms:modified [ a dcterms:W3CDTF; rdf:value "2010-04-06" ]
```

The reason that rdf:value even exists is for triples like:

```
exproduct:item10245   exterms:weight   [rdf:value        "2.4"^^xsd:decimal
                                        exterms:units    exunits:kilograms] .
```

In addition to units the node could indicate precision or other characteristics of the `object` of the triple.

Yeah I kind of hate the `rdf:value` thing as damaging to understanding and practicality in favor of epistemological purity.

Comment: "Why does xml have so many angle brackets my eyes hurt....because it was meant to be read by a parser not by humans." +1

Comment: What is the express purpose of rdf:value in this part of the expression?  Could it be anything other than rdf:value?  `[ a dcterms:IMT;  rdf:value`

Comment: @Mark0978 - nuts. I was hoping that you wouldn't come back and ask about that.  The short answer: that is the fault of RDF and not the serialization.  I dislike rdf:value, it should never have existed.  As for why it exists, I'll maybe edit my post (might go from 2 back to 1 example sets on serialization) or hopefully I'll find a good wiki post in my bookmarks and add that.

Comment: I think the most disappointing part is `dc:format` having 2 indistinguishable values (from the metadata standpoint).  You get 2 nodes, one of which is the mimetype and one that is the container type and yet with all this verbosity, you can't tell which is which without examining the content of the data, which to me seems to defeat the whole point of the metadata.  Almost seems like the guys creating this watched Robin Williams on Golf before laying this out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcnFbCCgTo4 .